# Response 401 when accessing PayPal sandbox Rest API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I was able to request an access token at `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` and send a `POST` to create a new payment at `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment` using the given access token. Those two APIs ran without any problem.

But when performing a `GET` to the payment_id that I created also using above access token, it gave me `401` `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX`. This is the step where I want to execute the payment at my `return_url`.

I'm using the PayPal PHP SDK downloaded from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK. Everything is still in sandbox mode. The `client_id` and `secret` are sandbox credentials.

Also, I have tried running cURL to above payment_id's URL yet it gave `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` as well.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

According to the documentation, `401` means invalid or expired access token but I don't think it applied here because the previous `POST` command could run successfully.

UPDATE #1: In fact, I have tried running the whole flow (request `access_token`, `post` payment, `get` payment and `execute`) using cURL and did not have problem. So the problem must be with the PHP code

Comment: Can you try running the [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples), and make sure they are working fine ?

Comment: For those that come later: Make sure to use the merchant email address that corresponds to the current `clientID` and `clientSecret`, otherwise you will get the `401` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was one typo in the PHP which gave me wrong `access_token`. Interestingly, the `POST` method to create new payment was still allowed that confused me.